# Are item rarities different on 50/100/150cc?

Tags: mario-kart-8

After getting Gold in all 100cc grand prix races I decided to start in on 150cc. Since doing so, I've noticed I'm getting a LOT more Super Horn items while in first place. I got maybe one in 8 Grand Prix races in 100cc, I'm getting almost one per track now.

Is the item list/rarity different on different difficulty/speeds or is this just a fluke?

Comment: I guess that it's speculation, but from my expecience item "randomness" in MK8 is totally rigged (you get different items based on your current position, for exmaple). So I guess it's quite possible. Given that CPU will be more aggressive and will use shells a lot, you are given more items that you can use to protect youself. Also I have played on 50cc and 100cc for now, and can confirm that `Super Horn` is quite rare in this modes.

Comment: Petr, all Mario Kart games have different item chances based on your position.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to confirm that at least the CPU players' item rate is different based on cc - I've never ever seen a Red Shell from a CPU in 50cc, for example, while they're rare on 100cc and more common on 150cc.

I haven't yet seen any proof as obvious as this for player item rate.